# php uploading file (powerpoint)

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using these codes to upload images and then I tried it to upload CSV files. These codes worked for both uploading images and CSV files, but it won't work in uploading powerpoint files. What am I missing here?

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["calendarformat"])){
$calendarfilename = $_POST['calendarfilename'];
$calendarfile = $_FILES['calendarfile']['name'];
$calendarlocation = "calendar/".$calendarfile;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['calendarfile']['tmp_name'],$calendarlocation);
    $quer_calendar = "INSERT into calendar (name,format,path) values ('$calendarfilename','$calendarfile','$calendarlocation')";
    $quer1_calendar = mysqli_query($con,$quer_calendar);

if ($quer1_calendar==true)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Upload Success');</script>";
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Upload Failed');</script>";
} }?>
```

This is the html form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
                            <h4><input type="file" name="calendarfile"/></h4>
                            <h4><input type="text" name="calendarfilename" placeholder="File Name"/></h4>
                            <button type="submit" name="calendarformat" class="btn">Upload Calendar</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Please show the html form

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
                                <h4><input type="file" name="calendarfile"/></h4>
                                <h4><input type="text" name="calendarfilename" placeholder="File Name"/></h4>
                                <button type="submit" name="calendarformat" class="btn">Upload Calendar</button>
</form>
```

This is my form, I already added the `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />`
 The PPT file is already saved into my database, but it doesn't went to the location folder which is the calendar folder.